# EF Core 3.1.1 Avoiding the exception "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator" just as LINQPad 6 does

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, linqpad

I am trying to run this LINQ expression through Entity Framework Core 3.1.1.

```
 using (Text3Context text3Context = new Text3Context(_constringText3))
            {
                var aus = text3Context.Ausschreibungen.Where(a => a.InhaltKurzText.Contains(value)).Select(c => c.InhaltKurzText).ToList();
            }
```

Unfortunately it throws the exception: "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator" however, when I run the same expression in LINQPad 6:

```
string value = "test";
var aus = Ausschreibungen.Where(a => a.InhaltKurzText.Contains(value)).Select(c => c.InhaltKurzText);
aus.Dump();
```

it works perfectly with no errors.

The sql-querys are slightly different as you can see:

Linq/EF Core:

```
SELECT [a].[InhaltKurzText]
FROM [dbo].[Ausschreibungen] AS [a]
WHERE (@__value_0 = '''') OR (CHARINDEX(@__value_0, [a].[InhaltKurzText]) > 0)',N'@__value_0 text',@__value_0='test'
```

LINQPad:

```
SELECT [a].[InhaltKurzText]
FROM [Ausschreibungen] AS [a]
WHERE ((@__value_0 = N'''') AND @__value_0 IS NOT NULL) OR (CHARINDEX(@__value_0, [a].[InhaltKurzText]) > 0)',N'@__value_0 nvarchar(16)',@__value_0=N'test'
```

How can I handle this query just as LINQPad does?

The sql-datatype of "InhaltKurzText" is "text", thats the reason of the exception, however, since changing the sql-datatype is unfortunately not an option, and the workarounds are "expensive" I would like to be able to run it in the same way as LINQPad does.

The version of the dependency Microsoft.Data.Sql.Client is 1.0.19.269.1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It has nothing to do with LINQPad, but the EF Core version used. Looks like ER Core 3.x is implying different db type than EF Core 2.x used by LINQPad.

Comment: can you try ``Like``, but not efficient : .Where(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.InhaltKurzText, $"%{value}%"))

Comment: @IvanStoev Both are using EF Core 3.1.

Comment: LINQPad's inference of the parameter type as `nvarchar(16)` (possibly mediated by EF) seems apropos of nothing. What happens if you use `12345678901234567` as a value, does it bump it up to `nvarchar(32)`? Arguably the best parameter type to use if it's known the underlying column is `text` is `varchar(max)` (and not `text` just because it matches), but that's another can of beans.

Comment: You should make the effort of changing the data type `Text` to it's modern replacement which is `varchar(max)`. The `Text` data type have been deprecated since SQL Server 2008, and that is one version older than the currently oldest supported version. If changing the sql data type is not an option, you better make it an option, otherwise, it will come to bite you later on.

Comment: @Sajid semms like an option, thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled: actually, `TEXT` and co. have been deprecated all the way since SQL Server 2005, which introduced the `MAX` types. The current docs just consistently pretend there's no version older than 2008. (Realistically, it seems improbable they will ever be actually removed from the engine, but they're plenty awkward to use as it is that avoiding them is worthwhile even without that 15-year old threat.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Well, 15 years is a long enough time to distort even important memories, let alone unimportant ones :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by some change in EF Core 3.x infrastructure and/or SqlServer provider. LINQPad is irrelevant because it simply delegates the LINQ query to the underlying framework (apparently EF Core 2.x in your case).

According to SqlServer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), `text` data type is obsolete and represents

> Variable-length non-Unicode data in the code page of the server and with a maximum string length of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647).

So even though the database type is `text`, you can map it in EF Core as `varchar(2^31-1)`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ausschreibungen>().Property(e => e.InhaltKurzText)
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasMaxLength((1 << 31) - 1);
```

Interestingly, the generated SQL is exactly the same (according to the EF Core log) as the one generated from

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ausschreibungen>().Property(e => e.InhaltKurzText)
    .HasColumnType("text");
```

but runs successfully, while the later generates the runtime exception in question.

Comment: This should be used with care, because if the first version infers that a `VARCHAR` with a maximum length of `2^31` is appropriate, this will fail for values larger than 8000, which is the *actual* limit of a `VARCHAR` that's not a `VARCHAR(MAX)` (but this may well be special-cased in EF for lengths exceeding 8000, I haven't checked).

Comment: Note that `(1 << 30) - 1` is not `2^31-1`; that's more compactly written as `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right of course, I just wanted to take the value from the documentation, but did the off by one mistake while looking here and there :-)